# How can I programmatically remove a stale dpkg lock file?

Tags: bash

I am trying to build a small shell script that would detect a stale `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file and would remove it if there are no running dpkg processes.

How can I do this? ... using preferably a one-liner :)

Comment: Just a guess, but try to delete it. If it is in use by some process the delete will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** remove the dpkg lock file. Its presence or absence does **not** denote that the lock is in place or not. dpkg uses region locking on a pre-existing file. It would be good if people stopped giving this advice.

Please see this FAQ entry for more information: https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_can_be_done_when_the_dpkg_lock_is_held.3F

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo lsof | grep -q /var/lib/dpkg/lock || sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Explanation:

```
1. lsof: list open files
2. | (= pipe to) grep: is /var/lib/dpkg/lock in the list?
3. || (= or) rm: no? rm it!
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to approach removal of a lock file in the manner you describe. (however, a more proper way is to create the lockfile (or lockdir for atomic locking), containing the `PID` of the running process). However, for the simple case you describe, you can use `pidof` on the name of the running process as another type of check.

(just be aware if you have multiple processes running under the same name, the lockfile will be removed and there is no correlation as to which process the lockfile belonged).

A short script for your situation making use of `pidof` (and subject to the limitations) could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" && {   ## validate required input/show usage
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s procnm [lockfile].\n" \
           "${0//*\/}" >&2
    exit 1
}

procnm="$1"                         ## process name
victim=${2:-/var/lib/dpkg/lock}     ## lockfile name

if [ ! -n "$(pidof  "$procnm")" ]   ## test pidof name
then                                ## if not running, rm lock
    [ -f "$victim" ] && rm "$victim"
fi
```

The script takes the process name as the first argument, and an optional second argument of the lockfile location. (presuming you have your intended lockfile hardcoded as a default). e.g.

```
$ bash rmlock.sh
error: insufficient input, usage: rmlock.sh procnm [lockfile].
```